# Finding a Common Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Letting $F$ be a field and $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, we have $U_i,\ldots,U_k$ distinct proper subspaces of $V$.  I'm asked to provide a condition on the $U_i$ such that there exists a subspace $W$ such that $U_i\oplus W = V$ for all $i$, where $\oplus$ denotes the internal direct sum.  My claim is that $\dim(U_i)=\dim(U_j)$ for all $i$ and $j$ is the necessary condition.  Moreover I want to know that this necessary condition is also sufficient, namely, there does exist such a unique $W$ in the event that $F$ is infinite.

Showing the necessary-ness seems reasonable in that each $U_i$ should be isomorphic to $V/W$ if such a $U$ exists, but actually constructing such a $W$ for the case that $F$ is infinite is tripping me up.  I'm assuming there's a clever way of extending the bases of $U_i$, but I haven't really been able to make that precise.

It may be that it's closely related to a previous question I posed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217494/finding-a-vector-not-in-a-collection-of-proper-subspaces)

As always, any and all help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $F$ is infinite. It is known that $V$ is not a union of any finite set of proper subspaces (I believe this is what the linked question is about). Choose $w$ in $V$ not in the union of the $U_i$, let $W$ be the subspace generated by $w$. If $U_i\oplus W=V$ for all $i$, you are done. If not, then for all $i$, $U_i\oplus W$ is a proper subspace of $V$, and you can choose $w'$ in $V$ but not in the union of the $U_i\oplus W$. Let $W'$ be the span of $w$ and $w'$. Iterate until you run out of dimensions --- then you'll have the space you're looking for.

Comment: Ah, very cool.  I'm just a bit unsure about the second sentence.  Here we don't have the hypothesis that no $U_i$ is in the union of the other $U_j$.  Does that affect anything?  Namely, do I still know that such a $w$ exists?

Comment: Whether some subspace is in the union of some others, doesn't matter --- it's still true that a vector space over an infinite field is not a finite union of proper subspaces. See the comments on your other question.

Comment: Bit of a late follow up, but if I wanted to make this 100% precise, I'd use induction yes?  But what am I inducting on?  Is it on $dim(V)-dim(W_i)$?  Or rather, $dim(W_i)$, since $dim(V)$ is held fixed.